# time differences for multiple events for same ID in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm new to Stackoverflow and looked at similar posts but couldn't find a solution that can capture time differences from *multiple events* from the *same ID*.

What I've got:

```
Time<-c('2016-10-04','2016-10-18', '2016-10-04','2016-10-18','2016-10-19','2016-10-28','2016-10-04','2016-10-19','2016-10-21','2016-10-22', '2017-01-02', '2017-03-04')
Value<-c(0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0)
StoreID<-c('a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d','a','a','d','c')
Unit<-c(1,1,2,2,5,5,6,6,1,1,6,5)
Helper<-c('a1','a1','b2','b2','c5','c5','d6','d6','a1','a1','d6','c5')
```

The helper column is the StoreID and Unit combined because I couldn't figure out how to group by both Store ID and the Unit. I want to sort the data to show when the unit was disabled (value =0) and enabled again (value =1).

Ultimately, I'd want:

```
    Store_ID  Unit    Helper    Time(v=0)      Time(v=1)       Time2(v=0)    Time 2(v=1)
     a         1       a1      2016-10-04    2016-10-18      2016-10-21 2016-10-22
     b         2       b2      2016-10-04    2016-10-18 
     c         5       c5      2016-10-19    2016-10-28      2017-03-04
     d         6       d6      2016-10-04    2017-10-19
```

Any thoughts?

I'm thinking something in dplyr but am stumped about where to go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a *Header* column that combines the *Value* column and the row number that distinguishes duplicates, then `spread` to wide format:

<sub>Didn't use the ***helper*** column, grouped by StoredID and Unit instead.</sub>

```
df <- data.frame(StoreID, Unit, Time, Value)

df %>% 
    group_by(StoreID, Unit, Value) %>% 
    mutate(Headers = sprintf('Time %s (v=%s)', row_number(), Value)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% select(-Value) %>% 
    spread(Headers, Time)

# A tibble: 4 x 7
#  StoreID  Unit `Time 1 (v=0)` `Time 1 (v=1)` `Time 2 (v=0)` `Time 2 (v=1)` `Time 3 (v=0)`
#*  <fctr> <dbl>         <fctr>         <fctr>         <fctr>         <fctr>         <fctr>
#1       a     1     2016-10-04     2016-10-18     2016-10-21     2016-10-22             NA
#2       b     2     2016-10-04     2016-10-18             NA             NA             NA
#3       c     5     2016-10-19             NA     2016-10-28             NA     2017-03-04
#4       d     6     2016-10-04     2016-10-19             NA     2017-01-02             NA
```

Comment: What is the %s and (v=%s)?

Comment: `%s` is a placeholder for formatting strings. Basically it takes other arguments in `sprintf` and put them in the places of `%s`s. `sprintf('ab%s', 5)` will give `ab5` for instance.

Comment: Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default - any thoughts on what? I haven't quite learned how to debug in R yet ha

Comment: What `dplyr` version are you using? try replace `row_number()` with `seq_len(n())`.

Comment: dplyr 0.7.2 but I am also using stringr for some earlier processing

Comment: got "Error: This function should not be called directly" - that's a new one

Comment: Can you do `row_number(Value)`? I am not sure why you get those errors. Something seems to have messed up. Maybe upgrade `dplyr` to `0.7.4` as well.

Comment: It's running but it's got 1 column for each event so there are 2,000 columns with my data set when really there should be 4-5 instances max per unit - does that help? Thanks for the help BTW

Comment: Not sure how you define the instances to be 4-5. Do you want to simply remove events more than five?

Comment: sure thing - ideally, I'd want one row per unit, with each column giving the date when the value was changed. "Value" is evaluated each day, but the columns should grab the day when the value changes from 0 to 1, or 1 to 0 and ignore the remaining days until it changes again. I'm not sure about the number of instances per RTU, but I would guess it wouldn't be more than 15 in this data set. Does that make sense? Looking at d5 in the sample data should illustrate this.

Comment: It makes some sense. But it sounds a very different question than you are describing in OP.

Comment: hmm - do you have any suggestions on how to tackle that?